# Windows Shares in Nautilus

Tags: windows, nautilus

How would I get a windows share to automatically show as a server in the Nautilus other locations?

I can enter the server address as smb://192.168.1.178/ or smb://hostname.local/

The other linux servers show up automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be multiple streams of bug reporting around this same question, none of which appear to be completely resolved:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1778322

https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/1828107

The basic problem is that the method used by Ubuntu's underlying systems rely, in turn, on a deprecated version of the Samba protocol for discovering/browsing those shares. Linux machines will likely still have that protocol enabled alongside the more modern ones, but Windows machines will likely have it disabled.

For a small number of shares, I would recommend bookmarking them once you've browsed to them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> from the desired share folder) as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for comments, I would have imagined that installing the mDNS would make it work, since for windows it can see all of the Linux computers.

Since most of the articles say the way to do it the more technical smb://192.168.1.178/ style then there isn't much motiviation it would seem